# Maximum Likelihood Parameter Estimation

Tags: machine-learning, bayesian, mle

Given this dataset:

**Color | Size**

Red   | Big

White | Small

Red   | Big

Red   | Small

White | Big

Red   | Big

and the following bayesian network: **Color --> Size**, I am supposed to find the maximum likelihood parameters for the bayesian network. What will the estimators be? I am not sure how to proceed here, so any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: For questions about statistics you would be better off asking statisticians on http://stats.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming a multinomial distribution for your Color and Size variables, you need to estimate the following parameters [image: theta]:

For color:

- [image: Theta_red]: red probability.
- [image: Theta_white]: white probability.

For size:

- [image: Theta_big|red]: probability of being big given being red.
- [image: Theta_big|white]: probability of being big given being white.
- [image: Theta_small|red]: probability of being small given being red.
- [image: Theta_small|white]: probability of being small given being white.

Which in the end are only 3, since

- [image: theta_white = 1 - theta_red],
- [image: theta_small|red = 1 - theta_big|red]
- [image: theta_small|white = 1 - theta_big|white]

The likelihood is the probability of the observed data given the model, in this case, for a dataset with n observations of color and size:

[image: D = {(color_1, size_1), ..., (color_n, size_n)}],

And parameters:

[image: theta = {theta_red, theta_big|red, theta_big|white}],

The likelihood is given by:

[image: Likelihood]

Since we are dealing with Bernoulli distributions here for the color and the size given the color, we can write it like so:

[image]

Where [image] is the count of observations that are red and small, and the other Ms are defined likewise.

Finally, by optimizing the likelihood function, you get the parameter estimators:

- [image]
- [image]
- [image]

Comment: How would the hypothesis that maximizes the likelihood function look like in this example? Is <Red, Big> a complete hypothesis?